# How to prevent critical section access with atomics in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I have a program where 4 threads are doing random transactions between two "bank accounts", at every 100th transaction per account interest of 5% should be added to the account.

This is an exercise for school I have to do, and in the previous lesson, we used mutexes which seemed very straightforward in locking a section of code.
Now we have to do the same thing but using atomics.

My problem is that currently more than one thread can enter `addIntreset` function and interest can be added multiple times.

this is part of the code where I check if it is 100th transaction

```cpp
void transfer(Account& acc, int amount, string& thread)
{
    ++m_iCounter;

    withdraw(acc, amount);
    if (m_iCounter % 100 == 0)
    {
        addInterest(thread);
    }
}
```

All threads go through that function and check for % 100 and sometimes more than one thread slips into addInterest. With mutexes I could restrict access here but how do I do it with atomic?

Maybe I could solve this somehow inside `addInterest` but if so how?
Inside `addInterest` is following code (if more than 1 thread slip in interest is added multiple times) :

```cpp
void addInterest(string& thread)
{
    float old = m_iBalance.load();
    const float interest = 0.05f;
    const float amount = old * interest;

    while (!m_iBalance.compare_exchange_weak(old, old + amount))
    {
        //
    }
    ++m_iInterest;
    cout << thread << " interest : Acc" << name << " " << m_iCounter << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you increment and read counter separately, and because of this `addInterest` can be called multiple times. To fix this, you should write and read atomically.

```
const int newCounter = ++m_iCounter;
```

Adding interest:

If it doesn't matter when you add interest, as long as it happens after incrementing the counter, then your `addInterest` is probably fine as is.

If you must add interest to the balance you had during the 100th transaction (even if it has already changed when that thread reaches `addInterest`), you must somehow store the old balance before you increment the counter. The only way I can think of is to synchronize the entire `transfer` by using atomic flag as a replacement for mutex:

```
// Member variable
std::atomic_bool flag;

// Before the critical section
bool expected;
do {
    expected = false;
} while (!flag.compare_exchange_weak(expected, true));

// Critical section here
    
// Unlock at the end
flag = false;
```

Comment: Thank you!  const int newCounter = ++m_iCounter; makes a lot of sense! I got rid of that multiple entries problem now. I actually think I might be ok if I dont do the interest on the exact 100th transaction balance ... however, if I would like to do the addInterest with the balance that was on 100th transactions, could this idea work:
after checking for % 100 load m_iBalance value to a variable and pass it as a argument to addInterest? in the end adding interest is a summation, balance * 0.05 and then addition. If I capture the value I can add it a bit later, would it work ?

Comment: @Jeekim That is exactly what you are doing now (there is no time difference whether you load the balance before calling `addInterest` or at the beginning of it). It is not reliable because after you have loaded the counter value, other thread might execute another transaction before you load the balance. So you would have to prevent other threads from executing transactions until you have loaded the balance.

Comment: Also, what if you are in process of adding interest, but other threads execute another 100 transactions before it is complete? Then the next `addInterest` call would load incorrect balance. This leads to requirement of locking entire `transfer`.

Comment: For your exercise, it's probably sufficient to explain the drawbacks in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Ok 2 possible solution:

- the first one is to use the `atomic` template that is in the header `<atomic>`, in this case you can make at least the `m_iCounter` as an atomic variable. but for a better atomicity of the operation all the variables in a critical section have to be atomic.
  Further read on [Atomic](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/) and [Atomic template](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/).
- the second option is use a sperimental feature of c++ the so called **STM** (Software Transactional Memory). In this case all the content of the `transfer` function could be a transaction, or anyway all the thinghs that you have mutexed before.
  Further reading [Transactional Memory c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory)

Comment: m_iCounter is atomic<int> , however how do I use it to solve problem ?
I tried to modifiy transfer this way that m_iCounter goes through CAS but it doesnt help, there is still mutliple interest done.

Comment: also the variable of `Account` and `amount`  should be atomic, maybe also `m_iBalance`